# Mecurial: commit automatcally returns "abort: empty commit message"

Tags: mercurial

I have been using mercurial for a few months now and just the other day when I went to do an `hg commit`, my editor launched but with an empty file named something like "/tmp/hg-editor-I48e8Z.txt" and in my terminal it automatically returned an "abort: empty commit message" error.

It had been working fine and it still works fine for other users on the same machine. The only way I've been able to commit is to specify the commit message at the command line. I really don't like doing that because I like that I can double-check which files will be included in the changeset when the editor pops up.

Does anyone know what may have caused this/how to fix this?

This is on a Redhat Linux machine, Mercurial version 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And of course, I just found out what it was...

I was setting my `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables incorrectly.

Comment: Yes: Mercurial must block and wait for your editor to finish before it examines the contents of the file. You were launching an editor in the background, so it was failing before you had a chance to write a commit message.

Answer (score 2):

I use gvim. With:

```
export EDITOR = gvim
```

I had the problem. Changing to:

```
export EDITOR = 'gvim -f'
```

fixed the problem.